# How can I configure the log of grpc Java client to output all levels of grpc logs?

Tags: grpc-java

I have a server and a client using logback as log framework, client and server use grpc Java to communicate with each other. Now I want to output all level of grpc logs, I change the log level to trace on logback.xml, but there are not all grpc logs output to the log file.

I add logging.properties and add -`Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties`, It seems not work at all.

```
# Create a file called logging.properties with the following contents.
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
io.grpc.level=FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

I want to output the logs of grpc re-connection attempts and all connect and re-connect actions. How to config the grpc logs?

```
add JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add these lines to enable it on the loggers level:

```
io.grpc.ChannelLogger.level = FINEST
io.grpc.xds.XdsLogger.level = FINEST

io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler = ALL
io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler = ALL

# If HTTP2 frames logs needed:
# io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2FrameLogger.level = FINE
```